# R file.info not working in if statement

Tags: r

This line of code returns TRUE if the file exits or NA if the directory does not exist.

In this case the directory does not exist so this line returns

```
file.info("M:/T/2014/")[1,"isdir"] 
[1] NA
```

Now I want to catch this case so I do:

```
 if(file.info("M:/T/2014")[1,"isdir"] != TRUE){
      print("there is no directory")
    }
```

But I get an error:

```
Error in if (file.info("M:/T/2014")[1, "isdir"] != TRUE) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I also tried:

```
if(as.character(file.info("M:/T/2014")[1,"isdir"]) == "NA"){
 print("there is no directory")
}
```

Can you advise what to do to put != TRUE or == "NA" in the if statement?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this using an `is.na` statement:

```
f <- file.info("M:/T/2014/")[1,"isdir"] 
if(!is.na(f) && !f) print("there is no directory")
```

Perhaps, though, you want:

```
f <- file.info("M:/T/2014/")[1,"isdir"] 
if(is.na(f) | !f) print("there is no directory")
```